# "Daily cap" badge counting - can the value decrease?

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-badges

Twenty minutes ago I *exactly* added up 200 reputation points today.

"Legendary counter" increased to 59.

Now, a few minutes later, somebody downvoted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283693/python-shade-certification-errors) of mine; so I am at 198 right.

Simply wondering: would I have to worry about that badge counter? Or can it only move forward?

(and more of curiosity "off topic" - any around who would have an idea what makes that question downvote'able?)

EDIT: by now 3 more people downvoted the question; telling me "bad question". Anybody dares to speak up why that is?

Comment: 91 remaining. HF!

Comment: I should downvote that question for you cramming tags in the title :/

Comment: Yay!  One less taggy title!

Comment: @Will Is there anything else I could do further change your opinion from "should downvote" to "probably will upvote" that question? ;-)

Comment: Money.  Definitely bribe-able.

Comment: @Mistalis 90! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) the relevant section we need has

> **Additional criteria for this badge family:**
>
> - All positive reputation activities, including up votes, accepted answers, bounties, and suggested edits count towards this badge
>     **except** for association bonuses, which do not count. ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88526))
> - Down votes cast or received do not count towards this badge. ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181103))
> - Each "day" lasts from midnight UTC to immediately before midnight, UTC; days are **not** counted in local time

So we can see it is only looking at reputation gained.  As long as you gained 200 rep on that day you will get the badge.

Answer (score 3):

Once it increased, it won't decrease. It also won't decrease when the question on which you earned let's say 200 rep gets removed or user deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As [@xenteros](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344417/4927984) already answered the main part of your question, I just wanted to give my opinion about the "off-topic" part:

> (and more of curiosity "off topic" - any around who would have an idea
>   what makes that question downvote'able?)
>
> EDIT: by now 3 more people downvoted the question; telling me "bad
>   question". Anybody dares to speak up why that is?

I don't know anything about Python, so I can't tell about the quality of the content, but in my opinion the question is well-formatted, and seems to show a research effort, so **I upvoted it**.

Anyway, if you have so many downvotes, ask yourself about its content:

- Is your question relevant?
- Does it brings something to SO?

As you are the only answerer, you may delete it (and also get back your reputation).

*PS: I think its title is not enough specific, I think you can find something more precise than "python/shade: certification errors"*

Comment: Well, those openstack specific questions have extremely low "view" counts. So yes, there are only few people out there that care. As a consequence of that, it is really **hard** to sometimes to find information on specific problems. Thus I am willing to keep this thing; as one day, it might become helpful to a single, desperate person. And that is worth keeping it even with well, 3 downvotes as of now. I don't mind the downvotes, the "no comment whatsoever" part is more getting to me. Thanks for breaking the silence here !

Comment: @GhostCat As I understand, your question is really specific. Maybe you can improve its title (it will also optimize search engine). About the *"no comment whatsoever"* part, I really think that [downvoters should not have to explain themselves](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284791/4927984).

Comment: I am not asking for mandatory explanations. I am asking to understand what is going on; and what I could do about that question. I almost always put comments to downvotes; and yes, sometimes that fires back in ugly way; but it also helped the downvoted person to improve their input.

Comment: @GhostCat It may be just the [**Meta effect**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251488/4927984): "A post which initially received little or lopsided attention may experience a wave of interest if it is subsequently referenced or discussed on Meta. This may result in an increased volume of votes or in "corrective" actions."

Comment: I understand part to. When I put up this question; and provided the link to the SO question ... I fully expected either ... some upvotes; or some downvotes; but I simply hoped for *explanations* on that downvote part.